# Why does my AWS Boto3 API request asking to create some Route53 records silently fail?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dns, boto3, route53

I have some code that has always just worked.  It uses the AWS API to request information about some ECS containers, then queries Route53 to get information about existing records, and then finally makes a Boto3 Route53 call to update a DNS zone to match the ECS information.

This code has worked in the past, but now I'm tracking down the source of some bad behavior, and the above logic seems to be the problem.  When I step over the ***Boto3*** call to ***change_resource_record_sets***, the call succeeds.  It doesn't throw an exception, and its HTTP Response Code is 200.  However, the changes I've asked to have applied to my DNS zone do not occur.  From what I can tell, the call didn't do anything.

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me why I'm getting this bad behavior. Why is the code below silently having no affect on my environment:

```
try:
    r = get_primary_client('route53').change_resource_record_sets(
        HostedZoneId=dns_zone['Id'],
        ChangeBatch={'Changes': changes}
    )
    processing_info['r'] = copy.deepcopy(r)
    assert r['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200
except Exception as ex:
    return str(ex)
```

The value of ***dns_zone*** dumped as JSON is:

```
{
      "CallerReference": "RISWorkflow-3bdd50ce72fe59acd56ed296752aab38",
      "Config": {
        "Comment": "HostedZone created by Route53 Registrar",
        "PrivateZone": false
      },
      "Id": "/hostedzone/Z30M8MWTQXQ2O2",
      "Name": "ourdomain.com.",
      "ResourceRecordSetCount": 54
}
```

The value of the ***changes*** param, dumped as JSON, is:

```
  {
    "Action": "CREATE",
    "ResourceRecordSet": {
      "Name": "appserver2h.devqa.ourdomain.com",
      "ResourceRecords": [
        {
          "Value": "10.13.11.98"
        }
      ],
      "TTL": 60,
      "Type": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    "Action": "CREATE",
    "ResourceRecordSet": {
      "Name": "grinder2h.devqa.ourdomain.com",
      "ResourceRecords": [
        {
          "Value": "10.13.12.172"
        }
      ],
      "TTL": 60,
      "Type": "A"
    }
  }
],
```

This code skips the except clause (doesn't throw an exception) and the assert statement succeeds (the request returns a response code of 200).  And yet, nothing changes in my DNS zone.  In this case, the following names do not have records in my DNS zone, as you'd expect after this call:

```
grinder2h.devqa.ourdomain.com
appserver2h.devqa.ourdomain.com
```

Here is a JSON dump of the what the call returns:

```
{
"ChangeInfo": {
  "Id": "/change/C102227247EPWZ3JJQCS",
  "Status": "PENDING",
  "SubmittedAt": "Tue, 27 Feb 2024 01:13:50 GMT"
},
"ResponseMetadata": {
  "HTTPHeaders": {
    "content-length": "282",
    "content-type": "text/xml",
    "date": "Tue, 27 Feb 2024 01:13:49 GMT",
    "x-amzn-requestid": "735f38f8-bd9d-440b-b29d-b68ebfd0f45e"
  },
  "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
  "RequestId": "735f38f8-bd9d-440b-b29d-b68ebfd0f45e",
  "RetryAttempts": 0
}
```

},

I did notice that the status returned is "Pending".  I had to read up on what this is about.  Apparently the changes are made asynchronously.  To get the status of my call, I do this with the AWS CLI:

```
> aws route53 get-change --id "/change/C06636843RDY913EELESJ"
{
    "ChangeInfo": {
        "Id": "/change/C06636843RDY913EELESJ",
        "Status": "INSYNC",
        "SubmittedAt": "2024-02-27T00:22:50.985000+00:00"
    }
}
```

A status of "INSYNC" apparently means that the requested changes have been made.

Huh?  I've been banging my head and staring at this for hours.  I can't figure out what's going on. Anyone?

Comment: You appear to be attempting changes in a subdomain, which in Route53 is a separate hosted zone.

Comment: @kdgergory - Thanks for you response.  What you say is apparently not true.  I have a bunch of names already defined just like the ones I'm trying to define, and this is the way we've defined such names for many years.  As I said in my question, this code has worked in the past.  I just tried defining a.b.c.d.ourdomain.com and I was immediately able to ping that name.  Ping displayed the arbitrary IP address I had assigned to it.  If I couldn't use Routet53 zones in this way, I would expect the Route53 API call to produce an error.

Comment: Hmm, you're correct; I'd never tried that before, but I guess whenever I created sub-domains they were cross-account. What happens when you do `dig +trace` with the domain name that isn't appearing?

Comment: And to follow that up: when I tried it myself, `dig +trace` showed multiple queries to the same set of nameservers (the one associated with the hosted zone). If you're seeing a different set of nameservers, it indicates that there might be an `NS` record for the sub-domain that you're not expecting. If it fails to resolve after working through the expected set of nameservers it might be time for an AWS Support ticket.